# LDAP groups by displayName on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, ldap

I'm using LDAP to connect to an AD instance for jenkins user auth and I would like to manage user permissions by LDAP groups

My Group search filter is set to `(& (objectclass=group)(displayName={0}))`

My Group membership filter is set to `(&(objectCategory=group)(member={0}))`

This allows to find the groups **by displayName** and add them to the Matrix authorization, but the permissions are somehow not working properly. For example, if give admin permissions to group `G`  and user `u` is a member of `G`, it can log in but doesn't get the admin permissions.

If I use the group search filter `(& (objectclass=group)(cn={0}))` instead, it works perfectly. **BUT**: my organization uses weird serial numbers as CN for the groups, so it makes it much less readable. That's why I'd want to find and manage the groups by `displayName`.

The Jenkins LDAP plugin doc says:

> Note: if you are using the LDAP security realm to connect to Active Directory (as opposed to using the Active Directory plugin's security realm) then you will need to change this filter to:

> (& (cn={0}) (objectclass=group) )

but, I was hoping I could still use the `displayName`, as jenkins does find the groups.

Can this be achieved with the LDAP plugin?

Comment: Probably not related, but to avoid problems with your filter I suggest removing the spaces from it.

Comment: Why aren't you using `objectCategory` in both searches? The idea is to have them symmetric, but it is also [what Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/deciding-what-to-find)

Comment: @ixe013 this is according to the LDAP plugin documentation for AD.

Comment: This is a tough one. I went to the code and it's hard to understand what is going on. What  I can't find is how the groups are stored (regardless of how they are displayed). The best practice would be to store them using their `dn` attribute, and membership verified in that group with the user's `dn` attribute, too. Doing so would support your use case, so there must be a glitch somewhere...